# how to get same result with Class, traditional function-based and object literal syntax?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to accomplish the same result using three different syntaxes? 
I already did the initial two but need help with the object literal

- Class syntax
- traditional function-based syntax
- object literal syntax **<<<---- missing ?????**

**Class:**

```
class Animal { 
  speak() { return this }
  static eat() { return this }
}

let obj = new Animal()
console.log(obj.speak()) // Animal {}
let speak = obj.speak
console.log(speak()) // undefined

console.log(Animal.eat()) // Animal
let eat = Animal.eat
console.log(eat()); // undefined
```

**traditional function-based**

```
"use strict"
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.speak  = function() {return this}
Animal.eat              = function() {return this}

let obj = new Animal();
console.log(obj.speak()); // Animal {}
let speak = obj.speak;
console.log(speak()); // undefined

console.log(Animal.eat()) // Animal
let eat = Animal.eat;
console.log(eat()); // undefined
```

**Object literal**

```
"use strict"
Animal = {
  speak: function(){ return this},
  eat: function(){ return this }() // ????????????????
}

console.log(Animal.speak()) // Animal {}
let speak = Animal.speak;
console.log(speak()) // undefined

console.log(Animal.eat) // Animal ????????????????
let eat = Animal.eat;
console.log(eat()) // undefined ????????????
```

Comment: In the third example there is no class named `Animal`. The object is created by the class Object.

Comment: Here's a link that explains implicit & explicit bindings to give proper context to `this` https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2a4ac91f9f42ec0ef9cd0d18e4e71262. For example: Animal.speak.bind(Animal) will return the Animal object as `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So object literal syntax would look like this.

```
Animal = {
  noice: 'Moooo',
  speak: function(){ return this.noice },
  eat: function(){ return this }
}

var cow = Object.create(Animal)
cow.speak() // Moooo
```

The Object.create() creates a new object, using an existing object (Animal) as the prototype of the newly created object.

So the new `cow` object with have none of its own properties, but its prototype will point to the Animal object.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to put a method in the object's prototype with just object literal syntax. But you can make it work with `Object.create` and custom constructor function:

```js
"use strict"
function Animal() {
  return Object.create({
    speak: function() {
      return this
    }
  });
}

Animal.eat = function() {
  return this
} 

const animal = Animal();
console.log(animal.speak()) // Animal {}
let speak = animal.speak;
console.log(speak()) // undefined

console.log(Animal.eat) // Animal
let eat = Animal.eat;
console.log(eat()) // undefined
```

Comment: Yes there is. See my answer

Comment: @ViktorGarba you're creating a method directly on the object, not its prototype.

Comment: Yes the method is set directly on the object, and then Object.create is used to define a new object with its prototype pointing to the object (Animal). So you've set the method on the object instance prototype.

Comment: @ViktorGarba you have to use `Object.create` to get that method to the prototype. You can't just do it with object literal syntax alone. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yea fair enough you can't just use object literal syntax, you have to use Object.create in conjunction with object literal syntax. But just because you have to use Object.create with it doesn't mean there is no way to use object literal syntax. And the question was how to get the same results as class with object literal.